# Solution of linear PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, solution-verification

I want to solve  linear equations, which can be found in the [article](http://xxx.tau.ac.il/abs/1308.2288)

> $\rho_t+\dfrac12[\rho(U-v\cos\theta)]_x=0,$
>
> $\Phi_t-\dfrac{\cot\theta}{2\rho}(p\theta_x)_x+\dfrac{\rho_x^2}{4\rho^2}-\dfrac{\rho_{xx}}{2\rho}+\dfrac14(\theta_x^2+U^2+v^2)+2\rho=0$
>
> $\rho\theta_t+\dfrac12[(\rho v\sin\theta)_x+\rho U\theta_x]=0,$
>
> $\phi_t-\dfrac{1}{2\rho\sin \theta}(\rho\theta_x)_x+\dfrac12Uv=0.$

The solutions are:

> $\rho=\rho(\xi),\quad\theta=\theta(\xi),\quad\Phi=-2\mu t+\Phi_0(\xi),$
>
> $\phi=\phi(\xi),\quad\text{where}\,\,\xi=x-Vt$

Can you give me some hints that how to proceed or solution.

Thanks

Comment: Where did $\Phi$ come from?

Comment: This doesn't look linear because of the $\theta^2$ term.

Comment: How will we know a differential equation is non-linear? How can it be tested?